# How to create method on slice

Tags: go

I have this:

```
type DbTransaction struct {
  Tx *sql.Tx
  DidTransactionFinish bool
}

type DbTransactionSlice []DbTransaction

func (v *DbTransactionSlice) push(x *DbTransaction) *DbTransaction{
  append(v, x)
  return x;
}
```

I just want a method that appends an element and returns that element. The error I get is:

> Cannot use 'v' (type *DbTransactionSlice) as type []Type

anyone know how to do what I want to do?

Comment: I figure I don't need to capture the return value of append, it will modify the pointer?

Comment: Not using the value `append` returns is always a mistake.

Comment: it's not always a mistake if it's using pointers and shiiit, although it is very non-functional but whatever

Comment: `*v = append(*v, x)`.

Comment: @AlexChannelmeter "it's not always a mistake if it's using pointers and shiiit" --- it's **always** a mistake, regardless of the value. You don't know the capacity of the underlying array, and the spec does not guarantee anything in that regard.

Comment: you speak with authority, but I don't trust you 100%.  this is a slice not an array, right?   `*v = append(*v, x)` is not actually doing anything. it's not a reassignment. it's the same as `append(*v, x)`.

Comment: "but I don't trust you 100%" --- then trust the spec. `it's the same as append(*v, x)` --- it's totally not the same. Behaviour of the former is predictable, behaviour of the latter is not guaranteed. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices In newer Go versions it does not even compile: https://play.golang.org/p/Bir5eI6_TU3

Comment: right it shouldn't compile if it's undefined/unpredictable (which I still don't understand why it's not reliable tbh)

Comment: @user12834955 Then please say "I don't understand" in the first place. `zerkms` has 242K reputation on this site, which means he has proven himself to be a reliable and trustworthy source of information, as well as being extremely generous with his time to people like you and me, and he's just trying to give you a direct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```golang
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

type me []string


func (m *me) Add(a string) {
    *m = append(*m, a)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    hello := me{}
    hello.Add("asdasD")
    
    fmt.Println(hello)
    
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/D9V8XgH7HWw

Comment: I just wrapped the slice inside a struct and called it a day, but this hopefully works, I didn't test it